# What is the most effective way to manage time zones in a PHP/MySQL application?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a web application that involves the use of timestamps. I would like the timestamps to display in the user's time zone with as little configuration as possible. Facebook and Google Calendar both update their displayed time automatically when logged into from different time zones.

What is the most effective method you've used to deal with time zones in your web apps? If at all possible, I would like to require no additional input from the user.

Here's what I'm thinking so far:

1. Store all timestamps in the database in UTC
2. Keep a database table that correlates time zones to UTC offsets, and whether daylight savings time is observed in that time zone
3. Given client information (IP address?), find the user's current time zone. This information can be cached in a session variable to prevent repeated reads to the table.
4. Whenever a timestamp from the database is to be displayed, convert it using the UTC offset

I find it hard to believe that there's nothing out there already that does this. If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose another solution:

1. Store all the dates in mysql `timestamp` column type
2. Right after connect to mysql - specify current user's timezone with `SET time_zone='<tz>'` where `<tz>` can be either `+01:00` offset or timezone name `Asia/Vladivostok` (for the latter  special timezones db should be imported by DBA)

The benefit of using `timestamp` is that it *automatically* converts the date to and from UTC, according to the `time_zone` you've specified in the current connection.

More details about timestamp: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html

About retrieving current user's timezone (even though there are a lot of answers here on SO about this topic, let's do that once again):

1. As long as there is a TZ value in cookies (look at step 4) - use it.
2. For registered/authenticated users - you can ask to specify their timezone and store it permanently in DB.
3. For guests you can retrieve the timezone from javascript (`Date.getTimezoneOffset()`) and send it with ajax
4. If it is the first request/nothing passed from ajax - guess it by IP
5. For each step (1-3) - save timezone to a cookie.

Comment: This is a good start, but how do you get the user's time zone?

Comment: This is a DB level solution.  It's burdensome if there's no reason for the current page to do anything with the database.  It also puts more work on the database which in mysql can be a limiter.

Comment: @evan: just believe me, that automatic conversions (performed on `timestamp`) are less burdensome than doing that manually like he said "Whenever a timestamp from the database is to be displayed, convert it using the UTC offset". And believe me once again, that performing TZ offset is such cheap operation - that you'll never be able to measure its cost.

Comment: @zerkms - all costs can be measured. If you haven't been able to, you haven't worked on websites that are big enough.  At Facebook we had novel discussions about the cost of sending the 'www.'.  Four characters more to read adds up with 500M users and billions of requests - let alone having databases do work that could be done by cheaper front end web boxes.

Comment: @evan: I still would prefer a solution that involves few cpu cycles (I'm sure that tz offset application is very cheap) than the one that is error prone and requires a lot of keystrokes to be done.

Comment: @evan I agree with you that there are far smarter ways to handle timezones than using the database but, dude, 'having 500M users and billions of requests' this is the least of anyones problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is a great solution.

The only alteration is in getting the user's timezone.  All you need to do is have bit of javascript report the user's time.  Then you know the offset.  That works even if the IP address is the same but the user updates the computer's timezone because it was incorrect for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've thought about it some more, used the info posted by some other people, and here's what I think the best approach is:

1. When a page is loaded, use Javascript to get the UTC timezone offset:

   `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`
2. Send this value back via AJAX to a PHP script. The PHP script formats the data into the form `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm`, and then stores this value in the current session.
3. For all subsequent database openings, run the query `SET time_zone="$Timezone"`, where `$Timezone` is the value cached in the session.
4. Use the MySQL `TIMESTAMP` type for all columns containing time data.

I like this approach because it lets MySQL do all the dirty work, and requires no huge time zone database that I have to manage.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: You omited the most important thing --- all date-related columns should be `timestamp`

Comment: You should always use appropriate data types. I edited the post in case other people don't know that.

Comment: @Zach Rattner Why not handle the UTC timestamp in javascript for display?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to solve this issue using PHP, check this out.
The following code can be used to find the local time and the Greenwich Mean Time(GMT).

```
<?php  
echo date("M d Y H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998));    # Local Time 
echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998));  # GMT Time 
?>
```

Use these steps to show the time based on location.

1. Add a Session variable which stores the difference of local and GMT time.
2. Add the difference to the GMT time before showing in the site.

For example,

```
# Here shows the difference 
$diff = (strtotime(gmdate("M d Y H:i:s",time())) - strtotime(date("M d Y H:i:s",time())));  

echo '<br />'.(date("M d Y H:i:s",time()));          #  Oct 16 2013 08:09:23
echo '<br />'.gmdate("M d Y H:i:s",(time()-$diff));  #  Oct 16 2013 08:09:23
```

Comment: Heading in the right direction with this, but remember PHP is a SERVER-based technology, so doing what you're suggesting above will tell you the difference between GMT and your SERVER's timezone. and if you're deploying your web application on cloud-based servers, for instance, you might not have any control over what timezone the server is in.  Based on the other discussions going on here, it seems like what's actually required is the USER's timezone, which can be obtained only by asking the browser using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` in Javascript.